# Capturing groups and money symbol in Regex

Tags: regex, parsing

I am trying to write a regular expression that takes a string and parses it into three different capturing groups:

```
$3.99 APP DOWNLOAD – 200 11/19 – 1/21 3.99

Group 1: $3.99 APP DOWNLOAD – 200
Group 2: 11/29 – 1/28
Group 3: 3.99
```

Does anyone have any ideas???

I do not have much experience with capturing groups and do not know how to create them.

i.e. I believe this expression would work for identifying the dates?

```
           /(\d{2}\/\d{2})/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Capture group basically just means put ( ) around your field of interest - so you can extract it.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex](http://regex101.com/r/hV7gA8):

```
([$]\d+[.]\d{2}.*?)\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{2}.*?\d{1,2}/\d{2})\s(\d+[.]\d{2})
```

So with this we have 3 capture groups (`()`) separated by `\s*` which means 0+ characters of whitespace (this isn't necessary, but it will remove trailing spaces from your captured groups).

The first capture group `[$]\d+[.]\d{2}.*?` matches a dollar sign, followed by 1+ digits, followed by a period, followed by 2 digits, followed by a lazy match of 0+ characters (`.*?`).  What this lazy match does is match anything up until the *next* match in our expression (in this case, our next capture group).

Our second capture group `\d{1,2}/\d{2}.*?\d{1,2}/\d{2}` matches 1-2 digits, a slash, and 2 digits.  Then we use another lazy match of any characters followed by another date.

Our final capture group `\d+[.]\d{2}` looks for 1+ digits, a period, and 2 more digits.

**Note:** I used `~` as delimiters so that we do not need to escape our `/` in the dates.  Also, I put `$` and `.` in character classes because I think it looks cleaner than escaping them (`[$]` vs `\$`)..either works though :)